# How to set limit value dynamic?

Tags: sql, limit

I'm using BI Tool which has an option to write SQL Queries. I have a tables like

Table Name - Analysis

| Module | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Lead | 5 |
| Deal | 3 |

Table Name - Leads

| module_name | Name | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lead | AAA | 03-02-2021 |
| Lead | BBB | 03-02-2021 |
| Lead | CCC | 03-02-2021 |
| Lead | FFF | 03-02-2021 |
| Lead | MMM | 03-02-2021 |
| Lead | ooo | 02-02-2021 |
| Lead | ppp | 02-02-2021 |

Table Name - Deals

| module_name | Name | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deal | DDD | 03-02-2021 |
| Deal | GGG | 03-02-2021 |
| Deal | EEE | 03-02-2021 |
| Deal | QQQ | 03-02-2021 |
| Deal | SSS | 02-02-2021 |
| Deal | TTT | 02-02-2021 |

The above values are not static values, they will get updated on an hourly basis.

I have to use those values and set the limit for no of rows to display based on the latest created date

I have to get output as

| Module | lead_name |
| --- | --- |
| Lead | AAA |
| Lead | BBB |
| Lead | CCC |
| Lead | FFF |
| Lead | MMM |
| Deal | DDD |
| Deal | GGG |
| Deal | EEE |

I tried the following

```
SELECT module_name as module,
    lead_name as name
    from Leads 
    left join Analysis on Leads.module_name=Analysis.Module
    Order by Leads.Created_Date DESC
    LIMIT to_integer(Analysis.Value)
 UNION
 SELECT Deals.module_name as module,
    Deals.deal_name as name
    from Deals
    left join Analysis on Deals.module_name=Analysis.Module
    Order by Deals.Created_Date DESC
    LIMIT to_integer(Analysis.Value)
```

Is it possible to set the limit dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: What do mean by " set the limit dynamically" ? Do you want pass the limit to that query? If it is, then you can use Store procedure. :)

Comment: yes. can you please explain how to get the output?

Comment: Please provide Leads table structure first and update your question. :)

Comment: Done. Please check now

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know it works or not. Best wishes . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `row_number()`:

```
select l.module_name, l.Name, l.created_date
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (order by created_date desc) as seqnum
      from leads l
     ) l
where seqnum < (select a.value from analysis a where a.module = 'Lead')
union all
select d.module_name, d.Name, d.created_date
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by created_date desc) as seqnum
      from deals d
     ) d
where seqnum < (select a.value from analysis a where a.module = 'Deal');
```

Note:  Use `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicate values.  And there appear to be no duplicate values in your data.

Also, the `LEFT JOIN` is superfluous.  Presumably, you would get no rows if there were no matches in `analysis`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was painful task, however I have written the code in MySql v8.0. If you are using lower version then you might not able to use `CTE`. On that scenario you can use subquery.So, Here is the code given below=>

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT module_name as module,
    lead_name as name,
    CASE WHEN
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Leads.module_name)<=Analysis.Value
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END AS IsSelected
    from Leads 
    left join Analysis on Leads.module_name=Analysis.Module
    
 UNION
 SELECT Deals.module_name as module,
    Deals.deal_name as name,
     CASE WHEN
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Deals.module_name)<=Analysis.Value
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END AS IsSelected
    from Deals
    left join Analysis on Deals.module_name=Analysis.Module
 )
 SELECT module,name FROM CTE WHERE IsSelected=1
```

**NOTE:** You can check my code in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gToAU78cdDDBEpSPwtRWfi/0).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'm not using MySQL,  as I said I'm using a BI Tool. I guess it works on MySQL v8.0

Comment: Oh ! then please change your question tags. It say's mysql and limit. That's why I did that in mysql. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In a Stored Procedure, you can construct a query and then execute.  That is a way to dynamically change the table name, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, and a few other things.

I prefer to make such changes in the application code.